# How render a block depending on a variable? PUG (JADE)

Tags: pug

First time working with pug.

The situation is such that all pages use the same header and footer.

**main-layout.pug:**

```
<header>
   h1 Some text
   h2 Second text
</header>
    
<footer>
   h3 Third text
</footer>
```

But on one page, I need to change half of the header, and leave the rest unchanged:

```
<header>
   h1 Some text
     div
      span Span text
</header>

<footer>
   h3 Third text
</footer>
```

How can i do this?

The final page has a name `map.pug`
and only has main page inheritance.

**map.pug:**

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it in several files e.g. with a version suffix. A parent file (header.pug) points to several childs and decides by a passed variable or takes the default (header-v1.pug) when nothing is given.

|-- partials
|-- |-- footer.pug
|-- |-- footer-v1.pug
|-- |-- footer-v2.pug
|-- |-- header.pug
|-- |-- header-v1.pug
|-- |-- header-v2.pug
|-- |-- header-v3.pug
|-- default.pug
|-- main-layout.pug
|-- map.pug

main-layout.pug

```
//- doctype, meta, etc ...

include partials/header

block content

include partials/footer-v1
```

header.pug

```
if headerVersion === "v2"
    include header-v2
else if headerVersion === "v3"
    include header-v3
else
    include header-v1
```

header-v1.pug

```
header
   h1 Some text
   h2 Second text
```

header-v2.pug

```
header
   h1 Some text
     div
      span Span text
```

The render call can pass the `headerVersion` variable:

```
return res.render('default.pug', {
    // nothing specifed: v1 is taken as default
});

return res.render('map.pug', {
    headerVersion: 'v2'
});
```